# I'm timing a function that has a runtime of O(n^3) but my timing results do not show this, why is this happening?

Tags: matlab, big-o, time-complexity

```
numberOfTrials = 10;
numberOfSizes = 6;
sizesArray = zeros(numberOfSizes, 1);

randomMAveragesArray = zeros(numberOfSizes, 1);

for i=1:numberOfSizes
    N = 2^i;
    %x=rand(N,1);

    randomMTimesArray = zeros(numberOfTrials, 1);

    for j=1:numberOfTrials
        tic;
        for k=1:N^3
                x = .323452345e-999 * .98989898989889e-953;
        end
        randomMTimesArray(j) = toc;
    end

    sizesArray(i) = N;

end

randomMPolyfit = polyfit(log10(sizesArray), log10(randomMAveragesArray), 1);
randomMSlope = randomMPolyfit(1);
```

That is my Matlab script. I was originally timing a NxN random matrix using '\' to solve. The runtime on this is O(n^3). But my slope for the log graph was always about 1.8.

My understanding from [this](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/JamesStewart/378notes/05logLog/) is that the timing results are O(n^k) where k is the slope from the log/log graph. So therefore the slope I should get should be around 3.

The code I posted above I have made an arbitrary loop that is N^3 with a floating point operation to test if this works.

However with the for loop I'm getting a slope of 2.5.

Why is this?

Comment: your code seems to be missing a line like `randomMAveragesArray(i) = mean(randomMTimesArray);`

Comment: You don't seem to do the courtesy of choosing an answer to your past questions; why would one want to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `O()` behavior is asymptotic, you sometimes cannot see the behavior for small values of N. For example, if I set `numberOfSizes = 9` and discard the first 3 points for the polynomial fit, the slope is much closer to 3:

```
randomMPolyfit = polyfit(log10(sizesArray(4:end)), log10(randomMAveragesArray(4:end)), 1);
randomMSlope = randomMPolyfit(1)

randomMSlope =

          2.91911869082081
```

If you plot the timing array this behavior is clearer.